# How do I resize my containers to remove overflow in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, layout, flutter-layout

I'm very new at coding with flutter and looking for help on something I am doing for school. My issue is that our instructor wants us to have padding on each side of our columns (10px) while also keeping our containers 1,2,3,4,5,6 width & height to 100px. What I am wondering is if there is anyway that I can resize my containers to fit inside my view without changing their width and height specified. This is the code I have and am open to any help I can get.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App01 Lucas Holmes',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
        // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
        // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Row and Column Widgets'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: Container(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text("Container 1",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3)),
                      ),
                      Transform.rotate(
                          angle: .8,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text("Container 2",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                    ],
                  )),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      new Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              child: new Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  child: Text("Container 3",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              margin:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10))),
                      new Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              child: new Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: Text("Container 4")),
                              color: Colors.lightBlue,
                              margin:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10)))
                    ],
                  )),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text("Container 5",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                    ),
                    new Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 160, right: 0, left: 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Con 6",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      ),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ))
                  ]))
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```

[This is what it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RrOc.jpg)

[This is the issue I'm running into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHZGq.png)

I was trying to see if I could get flexible to work but I wasn't able to get it to work properly. Sorry if my code is awful. I just started today lol. Our teacher said it is okay for us to get help from outside resources. So I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction in how to solving this issue. So close to done this was the only issue I ran into. Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Your problem will easily solve by using Stack widget. Calculate widget size according to screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also wrap Expanded widget to Row's children like this

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: Container(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text("Container 1",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3)),
                      ),
                      Transform.rotate(
                          angle: .8,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text("Container 2",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                    ],
                  ))),
            Expanded(child:Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                     Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              child: new Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  child: Text("Container 3",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              margin:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10)),
                       Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              child: new Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: Text("Container 4")),
                              color: Colors.lightBlue,
                              margin:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10))
                    ],
                  ))),
              Expanded(child:Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text("Container 5",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                    ),
                     Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 160, right: 0, left: 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Con 6",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      ),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    )
                  ])))
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to get to work. The expanded widget was exactly what I needed. I tried this previously but was using it improperly. Thank you so much!

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your container with `SingleChildScrollView` and set `scrollDirection` to `Axis.horizontal` like code below.
Remember because we have different screen sizes you should avoid to set constant value for width and height.

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Container(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text("Container 1",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.orange,
                              border:
                                  Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3)),
                        ),
                        Transform.rotate(
                            angle: .8,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text("Container 2",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )),
                      ],
                    )),
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    child: Text("Container 3",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                                color: Colors.yellow,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 10, bottom: 10))),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    child: Text("Container 4")),
                                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                margin:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10)))
                      ],
                    )),
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text("Container 5",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 160, right: 0, left: 0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Con 6",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        ),
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ))
                    ]))
              ],
            ),
          )),
        ));
```

Comment: Thank you! works great. He doesn't wish for it to be scrollable but it is  very close to the specs needed!